# different results if PreparedStatement is used as resource in try block

Tags: java, jdbc, try-catch

Some behaviour I don't understand.
I have a running script like:

```
ResultSet res = null;

String cmd = new String("SELECT value FROM " +pDS.getValueTableName()  + " WHERE itemID=? and propertyID=? ORDER BY checkpointID DESC"); 
PreparedStatement  pstmt= dbconn.prepareStatement(cmd) ;
pstmt.setLong(1,itemID);
pstmt.setLong(2,pDS.getPropertyID());


try {
    res = pstmt.executeQuery();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    throw(e);
}
if (!res.next()) 
{
   // other code
}
```

Here i get the expected values `res.next()=true`.
No exception is thrown.

I wanted to refactor the code, and use the Autoclose funtionalty of the try block, like:

```
ResultSet res = null;

String cmd = new String("SELECT value FROM " +pDS.getValueTableName()  + " WHERE itemID=? and propertyID=? ORDER BY checkpointID DESC"); 

try (PreparedStatement  pstmt= dbconn.prepareStatement(cmd) ){
    pstmt.setLong(1,itemID);
    pstmt.setLong(2,pDS.getPropertyID());
    res = pstmt.executeQuery();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
     LOGGER.error("Error at getLatestPropertyResultSet",e); 
    throw(e);
}
if (!res.next()) 
{
   // other code
}
```

However now `res.next()=false`. The resultset itselve is intialized `res!=null`.

Why did this modification change the behaviour of the script?

Comment: Where are you calling `res.next()`?

Comment: Added this information. After formulating my question, i now have a suspect for the root case. Please confirm: after the `try{ }` block `pstmt.close()` is called and additionally causes  `res.close()`

Comment: `try (ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery()) { ... }` too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing where you call `res.next()` I can only assume that the `try-with-resource` is doing exactly as advertised and closing the prepared statement once you leave the try block and thus the result is "closed" with it.

**update:** based on your edit my suspicions are confirmed. You need to move any work related to the resource inside the try block.

Comment: Ok, now I understand. Thank you for confirming. At progamming i wasn't aware of 'res.close()' being called.